Selenium Java: click button with CSSselector inside of shadow-root
I have cookie popup from here:
website
which I selected with shadow-root like this:
howto
now I want to click the button with xpath expression like this:
WebElement shadowHost = driver.findElement(By.id("usercentrics-root"));
SearchContext shadowRoot = shadowHost.getShadowRoot();
WebElement shadowContent = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']"));

shadowContent.click();

But selenium always gives me:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']"}

How to click the button right?
I am expecting the CSSselector button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button'] to select the button inside of shadow-root.
Looking for CSSselector "class" sc-dcJsrY.fMlgSq has the same unable to locate element error.
One more question is: can I verify the CSSselector inside of shadow-root in chrome inspect, too? Searching for the CSSselector in chrome inspect gives zero occurrences.
I read here that xpath isn`t supported so I switched to CSSselector:
question

Your problem might require simple thread.sleep() or explicitWait;
This code worked for me:
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#usercentrics-root")); SearchContext shadowRoot = el.getShadowRoot(); Thread.sleep(2000); WebElement actual = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector(".dRvQzh  .fMlgSq")); actual.click(); 
